# Sync Framework 2.1 Multiple Filtered scopes on same table

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

I am synchronizing databases. There is one main database and other client databases.

I created a filtered scope from a template. Set say UserID = 1 and then create this scope on server and client Database 1

Again

I created a new filtered scope with different name from a template. Set say UserID = 2 and then create this scope on server and client Database 2

But when i run schronization it is synchronizing with UserID =1 with both the databases client DB 1 and client DB 2

This is my code:

```
 private static void CreateTemplateScope(SqlConnection serverConn, string Template, string ScopeName, string TableName, string Condition, string ColumnName, string Operator, string FilterValue)
    {

        DbSyncScopeDescription scopeDesc = new DbSyncScopeDescription(Template);

        scopeDesc.UserComment = "N/A";

        DbSyncTableDescription customerDescription =
            SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable(TableName, serverConn);
        scopeDesc.Tables.Add(customerDescription);

        SqlSyncScopeProvisioning serverTemplate = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(serverConn, scopeDesc, SqlSyncScopeProvisioningType.Template);

        serverTemplate.Tables[TableName].AddFilterColumn(ColumnName);

        serverTemplate.Tables[TableName].FilterClause = "[side].[" + ColumnName + "] " + Operator + " " + FilterValue;

        serverTemplate.SetCreateProceduresForAdditionalScopeDefault(DbSyncCreationOption.CreateOrUseExisting);

        serverTemplate.Apply();

        SqlSyncScopeProvisioning serverProvRetail = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(serverConn);
        serverProvRetail.PopulateFromTemplate(ScopeName, Template);
        serverProvRetail.Apply();

    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Please let me know if you want more details

Comment: can you post the client provisioning part?  can you check the scope_info table how many scopes has been provisioned? how many _selectchanges SPs was created and what the entries are in the scope_parameters table.

Comment: @JuneT SOrry for the late reply i am using the same function for client and server. So in this case the same function above will be called four times

Comment: but your filter value is hardcoded to be always equal to "A"?

Comment: @JuneT That line is commented. I am not using parameters. I just hardcord the value in template itself and pass the values using function parameter

Comment: @JuneT I have removed the commented code now

Comment: sorry, didnt notice that...so how many entries do you have on the scope_info and scope_parameters table?

Comment: @JuneT I am not creating any parameter. I am setting the value in template filter clause itself. Will that matter. I did this as i dont know the column type in advance. The filter clause and column in configurable from the UI.

Comment: @JuneT Now with using parameter it worked in a new Database. Them what happened is i created a new table without filter and it sync well. Then i try to create a filter on it. Then it throws an error the parameter is not contained in a parameter collection when calling PopulateFromTemplate(). NOTE: I use the same parameter name as the old table filter one. Any ideas.

Comment: then i dont see the need for a scope template. the purpose of a template is to reuse the scope definition, especially if the scopes will only differ in terms of filter value. if you're creating a new template and a corresponding scope out of it, just create the scope directly. also, when you add a filter columns, they are added in the tracking table as well, and the triggers need to reflect that. so how many selectchanges sp do you have? have you checked if the triggers or tracking tables reflects your filters? one last thing, Sync Fx doenst support dynamic filtering if thats what youre after.

Comment: @JuneT The issue is i have X users. For User1 i need to create new filter and for user 2 i need to create some other filter with different condition. Whenever any user changes some filter. I create a new scope and new tamplate. Now as per you valuable suggestions i found out i created a scope without filter. Then created a new scope with new name on the same table WITH FILTER. The select changes proc does not changed and thats why throws an error. Currently i am creating a new scope for any change always. Thanks...... for the valuable suggestions.

Comment: you need to set SetCreateProceduresForAdditionalScopeDefault if you want to create a new selectchanges sp. i suggest you go thru this one so you know what provisioning does: http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2010/09/02/sync-framework-provisioning

Comment: Thanks @JuneT I will use  serverConfig.SetCreateProceduresForAdditionalScopeDefault(DbSyncCreationOption.Create);   Can i also use serverConfig.SetCreateTrackingTableDefault(DbSyncCreationOption.Create); Whenever a new scope is created or it will crash if there is already a scope on the table and the tracking table is created.

Comment: Please convert the comments to answer so that i can accept.